# Auto-refreshing content (using template engine) using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to use jQuery with a script index.php that is built bit-by-bit using a template engine, like so:

```
<?php

global $template;

page_header(); // Calls and displays header.html
$template->load('body', 'index.html'); // Loads index.html and calls it 'body'
   *Code that assigns values to variables in index.html*
$template->display('body'); // Displays index.html
page_footer(); // Calls and displays footer.html
?>
```

where each line does as commented.

I want to build a function using jQuery that autorefreshes index.php, but only the 'body' part.  I can't find any documentation on doing that, but I've looked at the following code:

```
function update() {
  $("#notice_div").html('Loading..'); 
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'index.php',
    timeout: 2000,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#current_game").html(data);
      $("#notice_div").html(''); 
      window.setTimeout(update, 10000);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $("#notice_div").html('Timeout contacting server..');
      window.setTimeout(update, 60000);
    }
});
};
```

But it gets really messy when this is in the header, because it calls the whole index.php page which nests the header, so we have a header in a header. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplest solution would be to send a get variable;

```
function update() {
    $("#notice_div").html('Loading..'); 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'index.php',
        data: 'ajax=true',
     ...
}
```

and in your php file do something like:

```
if($_GET['ajax'] == 'true') {
    // don't print header, but other stuff
} else {
    // print header
}
```

if you're using a framework it might have some intelligent functions to automatically determine if it's a xhttp request or a normal request. It is generally done by examening the headers

Comment: Thanks for replying. Would you know how to maintain a radio button selection on refresh?

Comment: well, basically you'll have to check it again. ie. by sending the form with the refresh (use jQuery.post()) and insert the html with php, or after the refresh use jquery to check it again. I guess the first would be the easiest

Comment: Thanks, that works. However, one little thing, if I change the radio button when the page has already started autorefreshing it'll put the selection back to how it was before the page started autorefreshing. This sounds tricky.

Comment: check out http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/, in the third parameter you can define a function which will be called _after_ the data is loaded. This will make it possible to check/uncheck radio buttons (or do whatever you want) after the page is already refreshed